# how to reference / import a Terraform module from another tf file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have my `utils.tf`:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_policy" {
    statement: {...}
}
```

and in my `main.tf` file I have:

```
...
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_role" {
    name               = "my_role"
    assume_role_policy = [...]
}
...
```

Now I'd like to replace the `[...]` and import the data module from the `utils.tf` file. Is it possible in Terraform? How to do that?

Comment: Are they in the same directory? Terraform concatenates all the `.tf` files in the same directory so you would just reference it as `data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_policy.json`

Comment: @ydaetskcoR that seems to be working! In my case wasn't working as it was in a different directory as you suggested but moving the other tf file it was correctly recognised. I couldn't find this piece of information anywhere else and for a beginner is not easy. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/58017482/2291321 answer your question? It can be tricky to search for if you're not sure but hopefully if you think it is a duplicate then we can make it a bit easier for people to find that answer.

Comment: yeah I guess that would have helped me anyway but when you try to google how to import other Terraform modules that answer doesn't come out as a result. Linking that answer to this question might be helpful for new users